# Bash script, read from file and write to other file

Tags: linux, bash, proxy, shell, shell-scripting

i have proxy server called 3proxy.
I need to add ip like this:

```
 flush
 auth iponly strong
 deny * * * 25,2525 * * *
 allow test
 proxy -n -a -i192.168.110.1 -e192.168.110.1 -p65233
 socks -n -a -i192.168.110.1 -e192.168.110.1 -p65234
```

This is a block of config 3proxy. I need to add in 3proxy more 100 blocks of config 3proxy with different ip. I write script:

```
if [ -f /root/ip ]; then
 for IP_IN_NGINX in `grep -v ^# /root/ip`; do
 cat > "/root/3proxy" <<END
 flush
 auth iponly strong
 deny * * * 25,2525 * * *
 allow test
 proxy -n -a -i$IP_IN_NGINX -e$IP_IN_NGINX -p65233
 socks -n -a -i$IP_IN_NGINX -e$IP_IN_NGINX -p65234
END
  done
fi
```

In /root/ip, i have a block with IP. In /root/3proxy i want to write many block of config with different IP. When, i start script, i have in output file one block of config 3proxy with one IP. But i need many blocks of config with different IP from my file. Where i have error ? Please help.

Comment: If you found my answer good, why not modding it up? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `>>` and not `>`!
With the former you append the output (or create if the destination doesn't exist) while with the latter you overwrite.